# Page css not updating in browser using npm node-sass and concurrent in Angular2 project

Tags: node.js, npm, angular, node-sass

I'm starting a small project to teach myself Angular2. As it is not fully released I have steered clear of using a Yeoman Generator and a automation tool like Grunt or Gulp. I am using the Node Package Manager and running my automation tasks from the "scripts" property.

I have installed concurrently, lite-server, typescript and node-sass. When I run a "watch" task to update when I change my source files a local server runs fine, this updates when I change any of my TypeScript classes however I have noticed that my CSS isn't being loaded despite the generated `css` being correct when I amend my source `scss` file. No CSS is loaded to the browser whatsoever. This is my package.json, you can see my watch script/task in the `scripts` object.

```
{
      "name": "my-first-angular2",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "clean": "rm -f ./*.js; rm -f ./*.js.map; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js.map",
        "tsc": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
        "tsc:w": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc -w",
        "node-sass": "node-sass styles/ -o styles/",
        "node-sass:w": "node-sass -w styles/ -o styles/",
        "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/live-server --host=localhost --port=8080 .",
        "watch": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run node-sass:w\" \"npm run serve\" "
      },
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16",
        "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
        "systemjs": "0.19.6",
        "tslint": "3.7.0-dev.2",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "zone.js": "0.6.12"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "typings": "^0.8.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
        "node-sass": "^3.6.0"
      }
    }
```

The generated css file is called `styles/main.css` and I link to it like so in my `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My First Angular2 App</title>
    <!-- Libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <angular2></angular2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can any one see what I am doing wrong? I get no errors in the console or the command line (in fact everything is working okay). Here is my folder structure in the Atom IDE:

[image: You can see the generated main.css]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the missing 'rel="stylesheet"' in the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">` tag was the problem!